# Replacement for iFrame to Load External Page + Information Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, iframe

I'm working on an app that needs to take people to external sites while presenting them with some options / information to use while there. The information has to persist from page to page as well.

Popups have proved confusing to people so the solution I've come up with so far is to create something like a social sharing bar on a dynamic page and then load in the shopping site via iFrame [see the mockup below].

This gets the job done except that:

1. Some sites [wisely] break out of frames.
2. Some sites like Amazon don't load in frames at all [affiliate fraud].
3. It makes ssl / security issues / phishing difficult to detect.
4. It's rude to the user to mask the url.
5. *It's an iFrame*

I realize cross-domain AJAX is no good but surely there must be a **codable solution** that presents a better experience?

[image: example page using a random rei product]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how complex you want to go, or what options you have, but you can set up a proxy to load the page and fake the user agents to get the requests to load in an iFrame, something like this:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-change-user-agent-string/

Comment: Interesting... The difficulty here is the user needs to be able to surf the site being opened normally. Obviously I expect limits in the url / navigation but am hoping to get past the frame limitations.